# Get first and last day of last month?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

This is how I currentyl get the first date of last month:

```
Frmdate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
Frmdate.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The result is `01/01/2015`.

When I am in february:

```
ToDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
ToDate.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The result is `28/01/2015`, but I need `31/01/2015`.

I need a way to solve this only for the month of february.

Comment: Those two code blocks are identical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `AddMonths` use `AddDays` function:

```
ToDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
ToDate.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nIFSK7) is a working fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Last month first day:

```
 DateTime firstDayLastMonth = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1 - DateTime.Now.Day).AddMonths(-1);
```

last month last day:

```
DateTime lastDayLastMonth = new DateTime(firstDayLastMonth.Year, firstDayLastMonth.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(firstDayLastMonth.Year, firstDayLastMonth.Month));
```